# continue executing remaining the promises on error

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, synchronous

I have an Array of promises that are processing a mail queue.
I am using `Promise.all()` to handle this array of promises.

```
let mails = data.result;
    let promises = [];
    mails.forEach(mail => {
        let mailOptions = {
            from: mail.mail_from,
            to: mail.mail_to,
            subject: mail.subject,
            [mail.mail_type]: mail.body
        };
        promises.push(helper.sendMail(mailOptions));
    });
    Promise.all(promises)
    .then(data => {
        // update mail queue status in the database.
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Now If there occurs an error while sending any of the emails then the code that updates the mail status in the database does not execute.

Is there a way to let the execution of code occur even if there is an error.

In other words, I want `then` to be executed everytime a mail is sent successfully otherwise `catch` should be called but the rest of the mail queue should also be processed.

Comment: use `map` instead of `forEach` + `push`

Comment: Do you want to update the mail queue status individually after *each* mail, or once after all mails were sent?

Answer (score 1):

For what I understand you want to execute `then` or `catch` for each promise, right?

```
const mails = data.result;
mails.forEach(mail => 
  helper
    .sendMail({
      from: mail.mail_from,
      to: mail.mail_to,
      subject: mail.subject,
      [mail.mail_type]: mail.body,
    })
    .then(data => {
      // update mail queue status in the database.
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
)
```

if that is not what you meant, comment and I'll try to help you out